# AWFUL smell from go kart motor

Tags: motor, troubleshooting

I built a mini go kart with an electric scooter motor (MY6812B-12) run off 2 AGM batteries in series and a control box (two way switch, forward and backward, middle is off).

I had ridden it around for a few minutes before noticing a strange smell. I couldn't quite wrap my head around what it was, but I thought I was just smelling trash - I had ridden past a trash can a minute earlier. So I continued riding.

I started up a small hill, and that's when I smelled it again. The kart started slowing down - it was like it was resisting something, as if something were caught in a wheel. The kart stops completely, and the smell gets stronger. So I switch it off and get out, and immediately notice that the wires leading to the motor are warm. I open the motor box and I'm instantly presented with an AWFUL smell. It smells somewhat like rotten fish, and its very strong at the motor.

So, I grab my hand tools and unscrew the motor, and try to pick it up, but it's REALLY hot. So hot that I can't hold it without it painfully burning me.

After about 20 minutes it's cooled down to the point of being somewhat warm, and I take it out.

It refuses to turn, either from a power source or by hand.

What went wrong? Was there some kind of chemical leaking out, maybe lubricant? What made that smell? I've smelled burnt electronics before, and this smells nothing like the burning plastic and ozone smell from fried chips.

Comment: You burned the motor. Probably you were using it well beyond 100W (but you didn't tell us your current measurements). See previous comment about suitable gearing and speed.

Comment: @user_1818839 I didn't see any "previous comment", maybe it didn't post properly? I never took current measurements, but at 12V the motor has a running current of about 8 amps and a startup current of around 20. Because its driving a heavy go kart, the motor is pretty much always drawing startup current.

Comment: It was on your previous question about this project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the smell of burning insulation on the motor windings. They're coated with a kind of orange-brown insulation varnish.

The motor is a '-12' model which is 12 V. You have powered it at 24 V which will push twice the rated current into it. Twice the voltage × twice the current = 4 times the power. You have overvolted the motor and destroyed it.

Comment: So I guess that means time for a new motor, huh.

Comment: Any compatible motors that can handle the higher torque? By "compatible" I mean the faceplate with the same places for screws, so it can be attached to the mounting plate from the old one.